# On-Premise Agent Setup TFS 2017 Fails

Tags: agent

Our code base is on TFS 2017. We are trying to set up Test Agents on-Premise on different machines so that they can share the load when running tests. Unfortunately, when running ./config command, we are running into the following error message.

```
    [2018-04-30 07:35:21Z INFO RSAEncryptedFileKeyManager] Loading RSA key parameters from file C:\agent\.credentials_rsaparams
[2018-04-30 07:35:22Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] POST request to https://tfs-dev.cebglobal.com/tfs/_apis/oauth2/token failed. HTTP Status: MethodNotAllowed
[2018-04-30 07:35:22Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] OAuth issued token provider instance 16345490 failed to retrieve a token.
Reason: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}}
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.OAuth.VssOAuthTokenHttpClient.<GetTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.OAuth.VssOAuthTokenProvider.<OnGetTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
[2018-04-30 07:35:22Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Authentication failed with status code 401.
Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 07:35:22 GMT
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer, Basic realm="tfs-dev.cebglobal.com", Negotiate, NTLM
X-TFS-ProcessId: 6ff0ab0f-5bc4-4756-bf8b-f1e2d9aec72d
ActivityId: cc1dfe13-8178-4102-984c-dc5587ffe193
X-TFS-Session: 2fbb527d-d145-4ffd-934b-44ab2bf4a0c9
X-VSS-E2EID: 22cf0b80-4ec5-4f2d-8730-aaaa26fe96fa
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-TFS-SoapException: %3c%3fxml+version%3d%221.0%22+encoding%3d%22utf-8%22%3f%3e%3csoap%3aEnvelope+xmlns%3asoap%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2003%2f05%2fsoap-envelope%22%3e%3csoap%3aBody%3e%3csoap%3aFault%3e%3csoap%3aCode%3e%3csoap%3aValue%3esoap%3aReceiver%3c%2fsoap%3aValue%3e%3csoap%3aSubcode%3e%3csoap%3aValue%3eUnauthorizedRequestException%3c%2fsoap%3aValue%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aSubcode%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aCode%3e%3csoap%3aReason%3e%3csoap%3aText+xml%3alang%3d%22en%22%3eTF400813%3a+Resource+not+available+for+anonymous+access.+Client+authentication+required.%3c%2fsoap%3aText%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aReason%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aFault%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aBody%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aEnvelope%3e
X-TFS-ServiceError: TF400813%3a+Resource+not+available+for+anonymous+access.+Client+authentication+required.
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Lfs-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

I have read many articles and have followed all previously suggested changes
1. Both Windows and Basic Authentication is enabled at TFS IIS level

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are the target machines in the same domain as your TFS instance?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure the target machines are in the same domain and have good connectivity with your TFS server.

Based on the error message "`HTTP Status: MethodNotAllowed`", generally it should be the `HTTP 405 Errors` which is caused when an HTTP method is not allowed by a web server for a requested URL. This condition is often seen when a **particular handler has been defined for a specific verb, and that handler is overriding the handler that you expect to process the request** or have somthing wrong with the URL.

So just try to check your TFS server settings and troubleshoot the issue following below article:

[Resolving HTTP 405 Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications#resolving-http-405-errors)

Other related threads for your reference:

- [OAuth2, Using POST and Yet... Method Not Allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685286/oauth2-using-post-and-yet-method-not-allowed?rq=1)
- [405 POST method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983222/405-post-method-not-allowed)